# Is there a way to update document field with FieldValue.increment() using firestore security rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I just started to use noSQL database like firestore and want to find how to increment document field from one collection after creating a document in second collection using firestore security rules.

js code

```
collection('some_collections').add({name: 'name', anotherId: 'abc' })
 .then(() => {
   collection.('another_collections').doc('abc')
   .update({counter: FieldValue.increment(1) });
});
```

something like this in security rules

```
function isIncremented() {
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/another_collections
      /$(request.resource.data.anotherId)).counter = FieldValue.increment(1);
      return true;
    }

 match /some_collections/{some_collectionId} {
        allow create: if signedIn() && isIncremented();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use security rules to modify any data in the database.

If you need to make changes to a document automatically when another document is changed, you should look into Cloud Functions to set up a trigger that executes after a document is changed.